# MVC Razor Var data

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, var

Hi i am new to MVC3 Razor .

I was trying to display the values from the database table.

in controller i wrote the code as

```
            var test1 = from ed in db.EmpDetails
            join dp in db.Departments on ed.EmpDept equals dp.DeptId
                select new
                {
                    EmpId = ed.EmpId,
                    EmpName = ed.EmpName,
                    EmpDesignation = ed.EmpDesignation,
                    EmpSalary = ed.EmpSalary,
                    EmpUserName =ed.EmpUserName,
                    EmpDept =ed.EmpDept,
                    deptName = dp.deptName
                };

        ViewBag.test = test1;
```

and in the view

```
               @foreach (var tm in ViewBag.test)
                {

                     string abc =@tm.EmpName; 
                     // and the logic
                 }


Here i am getting all the value in the "tm" variable. But when i try to get the particular value of EmpName in a string it is showing the error as "'object' does not contain a definition for 'EmpName'".
```

Please help me to solve this error.
Thanks
san

Comment: Why not just use a strong type model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get the values in the view if i convert linq result to toList() in controller.

```
    Like
```

var test = (from p in db.EmpDetails orderby p.EmpName ascending  select p).ToList();
  ViewBag.test = test;

```
    And in the view 

   @foreach (var tm in ViewBag.test)
   {
           int emId = @tm.id;
    }
```

Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately anonymous objects doesn't work with Views. Either you need to return a non-anonymous to view Or return a dynamic object to view.

Refer : http://rhizohm.net/irhetoric/post/2011/05/25/Taking-The-M-out-of-MVC-JSON-The-dynamic-Keyword-LINQ-.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use anonymous objects in views. Try like this:

```
var test1 = 
    from ed in db.EmpDetails
    join dp in db.Departments on ed.EmpDept equals dp.DeptId
    select ed;
ViewBag.test = test1;
```

and then:

```
@foreach (var tm in (IEnumerable<Employee>)ViewBag.test)
{
    string abc = tm.EmpName; 
    // and the logic
}
```

But personally I would recommend you using strongly typed views instead of ViewBag:

```
var test1 = 
    from ed in db.EmpDetails
    join dp in db.Departments on ed.EmpDept equals dp.DeptId
    select ed;
return View(test1);
```

and inside the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Employee>
@foreach (var tm in Model)
{
    string abc = tm.EmpName; 
    // and the logic
}
```